The tensor product of two Fredholm operators
What can be  said  about the  tensor  product $T\otimes S$ of  two  Fredholm operators $T:X_1\to Y_1$ and  $S:X_2 \to Y_2$  where $X_1,X_2,Y_1, Y_2$ are  Banach  spaces and  tensor  product of  operators are  considered on the  projective  tensor  product of  underling Banach  spaces? Is the  index of tensor product operator $T\otimes S$   bounded by the index of  $T$ and index of $S$? What about if  we replace  the  projective  tensor  product with other types of Banach space tensor  product norm?

As a  particular  case what is a precise  formula  for  the tensor  product of  two Laplacian operators on a Riemannian  manifold?  Namely  assume that we  have  two Riemannian  metrics $g_1,g_2$ on $M$  with  corresponding  Laplacian $\Delta_{g_1}, \Delta_{g_2}$. Is $\Delta_{g_1}\otimes \Delta_{g_2}$  a  Laplacian of a  metric  on $M$?


The tensor product $L^2(M,g_1) \otimes L^2(M,g_2)$ is canonically isomorphic to $L^2(M \times M,g_1 \oplus g_2)$, where, by abuse of notation, $g_1 \oplus g_2$ denotes the metric on $M \times M$ induced from $g_1$ and $g_2$  via the canonical isomorphism $T(M \times M) \cong \operatorname{Proj_1}^\ast TM \oplus \operatorname{Proj_2}^\ast TM$. Then $\Delta_{g_1 \oplus g_2}$ can identified with $\Delta_{g_1} \otimes I + I \otimes \Delta_{g_2}$, not $\Delta_{g_1} \otimes \Delta_{g_2}$.

Why would $T \otimes S$ even be Fredholm? If $T$ has a nontrivial kernel and $\text{dim}(X_2) = \infty$, then $T \otimes S$ has infinite-dimensional kernel and so is not Fredholm, no?

@BranimirĆaćić Thanks for your comment

@DavidGao Thanks for your comment

So in the compact case there is no any harmonic map so there is a chance of ellupticity (since there is no immediate obstruction for Fredholm ness of tensor product of laplacians). Yes the Laplacian of product metric is not the tensor product of corresponding Laplaciqn but what about possible...

@BranimirĆaćić ..possible other metrics

@BranimirĆaćić  But very good point you indicated to

@DavidGao Very good point. A similar point for codimension?

I mean module constant functions

@AliTaghavi That's impossible since $\Delta_{g_1} \otimes \Delta_{g_2}$ is a fourth-order [!!!] partial differential operator. For example, if $M = \mathbb{R}$ and $g_1 = g_2$ is the usual flat metric, then $\Delta_{g_1} = \Delta_{g_2} = -\tfrac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$ and $\Delta_{g_1} \otimes \Delta_{g_2}$ can be identified with $(-\partial_1^2)(-\partial_2^2) = \partial_1^2\partial_2^2$ on  $M \times M = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual flat metric.

@BranimirĆaćić  Yes but in the post I did not product manifolds. The tensor  product of $\epsilon_1$  with itself is the trivial line bundle on $M$(The base space is always $M$. so $f(x)\otimes g(x)$ is identified  with $f(x)g(x)$ So I guess I am leading to triviality!! because $f\otimes 1$ maps to 0 !!    am Imissing some thing? how can I improve the question in Riemannian metric case?

The tensor product $L^2(M,g_1) \otimes L^2(M,g_2)$ is canonically isomorphic to $L^2(M \times M,g_1 \oplus g_2)$, so I'm afraid I don't understand what you're hoping for.

@BranimirĆaćić  Sorry if the point is trivial: where is the  contraditory point: The  trivial line bundle on R is  denoted by $\epsilon_1$ then $\epsilon_1\otimes \epsilon_1 \sim \epsilon_1$ then the  section space of  tensor product is isomorphisc to the tensor product of the  corresponding sectioin(Serre Swan theorem). On the  other hand the isomorphisms between $\mathbb{R}\otimes \mathbb{R}$  with  $\mathbb{R}$ is in the form $a\otimes b \mapsto ab$. Now  we wish to look at  $\Delta \otimes \Delta$ acted on , say $x^6$... ok..

So $x^6\otimes 1$ is maped to 0  but $x^3\otimes x^3$ is maped to $6x\otimes 6x$ identified to $36x^2$. I think I am doing a stupid mistake  but what is my mistake?(I repeat that I do not  product M  with M. I just consider the  tensor trivial bundle and the tensor operrator.

It follows from Serre–Swan that if $E$ and $F$ are Hermitian vector bundles over $M$ compact, then $L^2(M,E \otimes F) \cong \Gamma_{\mathrm{cts}}(M,E) \otimes_{C(M)} L^2(M,F)$, which is a balanced tensor product over the $C^\ast$-algebra $C(M)$. You may be thinking of the process of twisting a Dirac-type operator by a Hermitian vector bundle with connection, which does not involve producing a new Fredholm operator via a straightforward tensor product of Fredholm operators.

@BranimirĆaćić   Yes  I see  in fact the  problem is that the  Laplacian is  not  $C^{\infty}(M) $ linear.  However  the  tensor product in your  first comment is  taken over  scalars.

Because your question involves a tensor product over the scalars, not a balanced tensor product.

@AliTaghavi Yes. Unless $T$ and $S$ are both bijective, or if some of the spaces involved are finite-dimensional, $T \otimes S$ can never be Fredholm.
